# How to fix "Unidentified Network" with iSCSI NICs?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a 2008 R2 server which has NICs on the production LAN and NICs connected to a dedicated iSCSI LAN.

Whilst everything seems to work just fine, the iSCSI NICs show as "Unidentified Network" when I look at the NICs in Control Panel.

Is there a way I can change this?  They aren't unidentified, I know exactly what they are, but there doesn't appear to be a simple way to change this, not that I can see anyway.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link applies to the VirtualBox network adapter, but I think it is related. http://www.brokenwire.net/bw/Various/120/fix-virtualbox-causes-unidentified-network-on-vista-and-windows-7

You need to tell Windows that the iSCSI NIC device is really an endpoint and not a connection to another network. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557037.aspx for more details. The reg key you need to add is *NdisDeviceType. Make sure you check the driver description so you change it on the correct interface!

Comment: What a faff!  Thanks very much though!